# Why does my strategy close at the end of the candle and not in real time?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

and thank you for your welcome on this space. I'm an amateur and I'm only starting to make a few indicators. Currently I'm stuck on one thing, I'm looking to make a stop loss function that takes effect immediately when an event occurs, currently it occurs at the close of the candle (I tried with strategy.exit, strategy.close and that does not work). Thank you for you precious help.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=5

strategy(
     "My Strategy",
     overlay=true,
     calc_on_every_tick=true,
     currency=currency.USD
     )

// Input EMA

emaFast = input.int(title="Fast EMA", defval=10, minval=1, maxval=9999)
emaSlow = input.int(title="Slow EMA", defval=20, minval=1, maxval=9999)

// Use the built-in function to calculate two EMA lines

fastEMA = ta.ema(close, emaFast)
slowEMA = ta.ema(close, emaSlow)

// Submit entry orders

if ta.crossover(fastEMA, slowEMA) 
    strategy.entry("Enter", strategy.long)

// Enter price

lastEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)

//Exit

if close > lastEntryPrice * 1.03
    strategy.close("Enter", immediately = true)

if close < lastEntryPrice * 0.97
    strategy.close("Enter", immediately = true)
```

the strategy takes the closing price into account, I would like it to take the precise price at the moment the event occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try - without if - with strategy.exit :

```
strategy.exit("up", from_entry"Enter", limit = lastEntryPrice * 1.03, stop = lastEntryPrice * 1.03)
```

Comment: That's also what I was saying, I tested but there too the backtesting takes into account the closing price of the candle and not the real moment with huge differences sometimes. Thanks.

Comment: @Samuel Yes indeed, if you haven't a premium account, you can backtest only on closed bar. If you have a premium account, you will have intrabar value : https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/accurate-backtesting-with-bar-magnifier-31746/

Comment: @G.Lebret dome clarification for your comment: strategy use intrabar values at any account, for free account bar has only 4 values: open, high, low, close, but for premium you may use Bar Magnifier that has more intrabar values from lower resolution
more: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#broker-emulator